# HikariConfig ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, hikaricp

I'm trying to use hikari with Eclipse Luna 4.4.2. I added these to my project java build path:

HikariCP-java6-2.3.8.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar
slf4j-simple-1.7.9.jar

My jre is 1.8.0_45

I'm getting ClassNotFoundException on this line:

```
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding javaassist.jar sovled a problem...